# ID a movie with an attacking toy tank and a wild cat ambush

Tags: story-identification, movie

Okay, there's this old movie maybe from the 1990's or earlier and I don't know the name of it. It has this scene where there is a bullet-shooting small toy tank shooting at this young man in some building/house. The man I think puts a blanket over it to stop it. There's also a wild cat ready to jump at him when he enters another room. The man was young and had black hair... Btw it wasn't a cartoon, it had real people.

Comment: Is there anything else you can remember form the film? It sounds vaguely like *Small Soldiers*, but I don't recall this particular scene.

Comment: Not really, it's like a really old movie... The only insignificant part I can remember is the man calling some other guy on the phone, looking tired and worried...

Comment: Was it a cartoon? Live-action with CG? All CG? Live-action with stop motion/puppets?

Comment: It put me in mind of "Cat's Eye" (1985) but I don't remember whether the baddies used a toy tank?

Comment: Reminds me of "Battleground" by Stephen King. But only matches partially. It was aired in 2006, the man wasn't young. Another one is the movie Toys (1992) with Robin Williams.

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/173635/early-2000s-or-late-90s-movie-of-a-toy-store-with-living-toys

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are referring to the movie, "Small Soldiers".

Plot line:

> When missile technology is used to enhance toy action figures, the
>   toys soon begin to take their battle programming too seriously.

From the link: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0122718/

Best Luck!

Comment: Do you recall if the movie had scenes like those mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty certain you're talking about *[Xtro](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086610/)*, an absolutely insane British Scif Fi horror from 1983. I saw it on VHS a few years after it came out. I was only 11, I think. It was one of the first horror movies I ever saw.

Comment: Which of the recollected scenes from the question match up with scenes from *Xtro*?

Comment: http://youtu.be/L0jhcNwLLs4?t=1h2m20s

Comment: @phantom42 Which scenes match up? The bit with a bullet-shooting tank chasing a (not-so-)young man with black hair through a house. Oh, and the bit where said man throws a towel on top of it before encountering a puma that jumps up at him. Like I said, batshit insane. I posted a link to this scene above.