# Early 2000's or late 90's movie of a toy store with living toys?

Tags: story-identification, movie

When I was young I watched this movie I have limited vivid snapshot of the film, but I think it was a kid who (a boy about 9-13) who visits this toystore and for some reasons the toys were alive. I can also recall that they were also rival toys (villains) who wanted to bomb the area with tanks and the other toys (on boys side) tried to stop them. Please if anyone has a clue on the name of the movie.

I know it's not **Toy Story** nor animation (real people, with toys)I've searched for this film for almost 3 years on youtube and the net, no luck :(. It is part of my childhood after all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps this is [Small Soldiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_Soldiers)?

> Small Soldiers is a 1998 American science fiction action film directed by Joe Dante. The film revolves around two adolescents who get caught in the middle of a war between two factions of sentient action figures, the Gorgonites and the Commando Elite.

No references to a tank, but military action figures come to life and fight each other. There is a toy store in one scene. And it's live action.

Trailer:

Comment: Oh my, that's the movie. haha and apologize for the tank thing probably confused it with @1:19. I was just a kid after all. but big thanks guys, I appreciate it.